# How can I toggle SetTimer off with a hotkey in AutoHotKey?

Tags: loops, timer, autohotkey

I am trying to write a script toggling a function.

This is an AutoHotkey 2 Script.

```
j::
    SetTimer "NewTimer", 1000
    return

k::
    SetTimer "NewTimer", Off
    return

NewTimer() {
    SendInput "NewInput"
}
```

Pressing J should start the timer, pressing K should stop it.
Currently, pressing K only stops it as long as I hold the key down.
How can I stop the timer with the key press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
k::
SetTimer "NewTimer" , "Off"
Return
```

`Off` must be in quotes, otherwise it will try to pass the contents of the varaible "Off". The reason holding K seems to pause it is because it's rapidly updating the period to the value contained in `Off` which is null and an error, so it reverts to the previous period of 1000.

Alternatively, if this is the only timer, using just `SetTimer , "Off"` also works.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider that excerpt from [the official docs for `SetTimer`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm):

> If hotkey response time is crucial (such as in games) and the script contains any timers whose subroutines take longer than about 5 ms to execute, use the following command to avoid any chance of a 15 ms delay. Such a delay would otherwise happen if a hotkey is pressed at the exact moment a timer thread is in its period of uninterruptibility:
>
> ```cpp
> Thread, interrupt, 0  ;//Make all threads always-interruptible.
> ```